# iOS6 Mobile Configuration CA Chain Change

Tags: ios, configuration, certificate, profile, ota

I used this page: [iOS mobileconfig walkarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277426/ios-mobileconfig-walkarounds) to setup my mobile configuration profile on iOS.  I had my SSL certificate/CA linked up with it.

All of a sudden iOS6 makes the profile show up as "Not Verified" when on iOS5.1 and under shows "Verified".  What changed or what changes can I make for this to show up as verified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is around which SSL providers you use.  Apple has an approved provider list that they ignored up until iOS6.

Answer (score 1):

Well. I had the same problem while signing my configuration profile with an openSSL command.

It worked well with iOS5, and "Not Verified" with iOS6.

Can you give me the "command" you use to sign your file ? It will make things easier to help you !